# Changing ListView.ShowItemToolTips raises ItemChecked events

Tags: winforms, listview, events, event-handling

Hi when I set `ShowItemToolTips` of a `ListView` with checkbox items to `true` in designer and change it to `false` in the code, the event `ItemChecked` is raised. The checked state itself is not changed though. But inside the (also raised) `ItemCheck` event the old value is not equal to the new value but the new value is the value that was previously visible. It seems like the items are re-inserted or reset in some way.

I tested this on two machines and projects. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Did a quick test with a MessageBox.Show in the ItemChecked event handler, and while the MessageBox is shown, the ListView has seemingly disappeared from the form..Also, the event only fired when at least one of the checkboxes was checked.

Comment: True. One item has to be checked. I guess it's a kind of item reset in the background. But shouldn't such side effects be documented? I mean I simply set a boolean property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll explain the "why", a workaround is hard to come by.  Some control properties are very impactful and can have odd side-effects when you change them.  Like ShowItemToolTips, changing it after the ListView is created requires Winforms to completely destroy the native control and recreate it from scratch.  Under the hood, it is a style flag (LVS_EX_INFOTIP) that's specified in the CreateWindowEx() call.  The Control.RecreateHandle() method ensures it is effective.  You'll see the flicker that this causes if you look closely.

So for a brief moment, the native control exists without yet being initialized with the original checkbox states.  Getting a flaky event for that is a bug, but it is the kind that was either never fixed because doing so was too difficult or was just never discovered because nobody ever changes the ShowItemToolTips property after the control was created.  It is very uncommon to do so.

In general, this native control re-creation trick has been a significant bug generator in Winforms.  And workarounds are hard to come by, they fit either in the "deal with it" or the "don't do it" category.  With the latter one strongly recommended in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I assumed something like that. And yes it is uncommon to change `ShowItemToolTips` at runtime. This might be the reason I found nothing about this behavior.